# FileNotFoundException for CefSharp when running XUnit test

Tags: c#, cefsharp, xunit.net

I am making some test with XUnit on a application using CefSarp.

But the test are crashing with the exception :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=55.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at CefSharp.CefSharpApp.OnBeforeChildProcessLaunch(CefSharpApp* , CefRefPtr* commandLine)

On Xunit issue tracker (https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/4) the workaround is to set the shadowCopy option to false. But this does not work for me.

CefSharp have some files which need to be next the executable (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies). All those files are present in the bin folder and when I check the current directory with `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, this is the right folder.

I tried to use the `SetDllDirectory` from Kernel32 to add the bin folder but it change nothing.

I also tried to load the assembly manualy with `Assembly.LoadFile()`. This call succeed but later when cef is initialized, the exception still happen. So the problem is probably not finding the assembly itself but the files needed by CefSharp.

Where should I put all the CefSharp file to allow XUnit to find them? I have the same problem with the Xunit test integrated in VisualStudio and with the Xunit console.

**Edit :**

Problem solved (see anwser). All the test are passing except test created with **SpecFlow**.

It throw the `Could not load file or assembly` but with CefSharp.Core this time.

Comment: Can you share your project/repository?

Comment: I can't share the repository. it's my company code. 
I will try to make a project with the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @robi-y I added a link to a repository which reproduce the issue

Comment: it runs on my machine :-), VS Community 2017

Comment: however, I did reinstall the Cef package @Gael

Comment: The CefSharp source has an xunit test project, you can use that for reference.

Comment: strange! this morning it was working then the second time I lauched the test, the exception was back.

Comment: @robi-y I updated the test. In the previous version, the exception happen but the test ignore it and succeed. You only see the exception in debug mode. I updated the test so it failed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that CefSharp does not support multiple AppDomains.
The config file of the unit test in the CefSharp repo contains the following :

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="xunit.appDomain" value="denied"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

which prevent XUnit to use multiple AppDomains.
This config must be added in the `app.config` of each test library .

The CefSharp test also contains

```
var isDefault = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain();
if (!isDefault)
{
     throw new Exception(@"Add <add key=""xunit.appDomain"" value=""denied""/> to your app.config to disable appdomains");
}
```

to check is multiple AppDomains are used.